# Having trouble with some bool/string issues

Tags: c#, boolean, code-behind

I've got some code-behind that opens like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        public DropDownList DDL_Reporting_RunForDaily;
        public bool _retrievedData = false;
```

I want to use _retrieveData in a session variable, so I'm setting it to false from the start.  Now, I have a "protected void" where I want to change the value of this variable, so I'm using the line:

```
Session["_retrievedData"] = true;
```

Lastly, in another "public void" I want to check the value of the session variable and only run it if the value is set to false.  So, I've got the code:

```
bool CanRun = (bool)Session["_retrievedData"];
if (CanRun == true)
{
    CanRun = false;
    return;
}
```

My problem is, I'm getting the following errors with that last piece of code:

- Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'
- Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and
  'bool'

Any ideas why I'm getting those errors?  When I tried changing the "==" to "=", I got an error that said:

- Assignment in conditional expression is always constant; did you mean
  to use == instead of = ?

Comment: Can you share us all of the code? I've got a suspicion, but I need to check it.

Comment: Which line has the error?  Have you tried using `bool.Parse` or `bool.TryParse` rather than casting the session variable to bool?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not terribly familiar with the Session object.
But to me it seems that the indexer returns a string.
Try this:
`bool CanRun = Boolean.Parse( Session["_retrievedData"] );`